# Pre-Approval of iOS Text Messages

Tags: iphone, ios, sms

Although Apple doesn't allow apps to send text messages without explicit user permission (unlike Android, which just requires you to ask for permissions like this when installing the app), I was wondering if anyone had any ideas for other ways to get around this issue. Specifically:

- Is it possible to allow the user to pre-approve a specific text message, and delay sending it until the desired time?
- Can an external client be used? Ex., ping a server to do the work of sending the text message for the user? This seems like it will get ugly quickly though (since provider info is required), and would require the user to have internet access, not just cell signal. However, perhaps the application can require an initialization text.

The goal here is to send a specific text message for the user when they are unable to do so themselves, so naturally, having them pre-approve the message would be impossible.

Comment: No. An app that did that would be breaking Apple's rules and would be rejected from the App Store.

Comment: Even if the text is not sent by the user, but an outside client? The only thing that matters is that the sms gets sent, not who by, so it seems like that wouldn't tread on the no-app-use-of-paid-services mandate.

Comment: Your app is still triggering the text, so yes, it's still in violation. Apple is not a fan of loopholes.

Answer (score 0):

You can't send text messages directly from the device.

But I think there is no problem sending them from a webserver, however your app needs to have an internet connection to do this and I am not aware of a service, which allows you to send text messages for free, so you need to pay to provide this service to your users (I can't say if it is ok for Apple to charge your users for such a service). Another drawback of this solution is, that the sender of the text message wouldn't probably be the users number.